# How to delete edited messages discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a bot which sends random GIFs but GIFs take long to load so i want to tell the user that, by saying "Gifs take long to load" then edit the message saying "Collecting random GIFs" and then I want it to delete the edited message. Here's my code:

```
if (message.content === 'zhood'){
        message.channel.send("*Gifs take long to load, please wait*").then((msg) => setTimeout(function(){
            msg.edit('*Collecting random GIFs*');
          }, 1000))
        .then(msg =>{
            msg.delete({ timeout: 2000 })
        })
}
```

This was the error given:

```
(node:12248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: msg.delete is not a function
```

I've also tried doing `message.delete({timeout: 2000})` but it made no difference.

Your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create another `.then()` callback, just continue in the first one:

```js
if (message.content === 'zhood') {
 message.channel.send('*Gifs take long to load, please wait*').then((msg) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
   msg.edit('*Collecting random GIFs*');
  }, 1000);
  msg.delete({ timeout: 2000 });
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with async/await like this:

```js
const waitMsg = await message.channel.send('*Gifs take long to load, please wait*');

setTimeout(() => {
  waitMsg.edit('*Collecting random GIFs*');
}, 1000);

waitMsg.delete({ timeout: 2000 });
```